# Hide content inside brackets using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to use pure JavaScript to hide all content inside brackets in a document. For example, this:

> Sometext [info]

would be replaced with this:

> Sometext

With jQuery I can do this with:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var replaced = jQuery("body").html().replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');
        jQuery("body").html(replaced);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use, document.body.innerHTML to replace, it is going to replace everything between [], even valid ones like input names.  So I think what you need is to grab all of the textnodes and then run the regex on them.  [This question looks like it will do the trick.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178174/find-all-text-nodes)

```
function recurse(element)
{
    if (element.childNodes.length > 0) 
        for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) 
            recurse(element.childNodes[i]);

    if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(element.nodeValue)){
         element.nodeValue = element.nodeValue.replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // This hits the entire document.
  // var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
  // recurse(html);

  // This touches only the elements with a class of 'scanME'
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('scanME');
  for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    recurse(nodes[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Andrei Edited so that it works, and added code so that it only hits specific nodes, instead of everything in the document.

Answer (score 2):

[The `document`'s `DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) will fire at the same time as the callback you pass to [`jQuery(document).ready(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

You can access the body of the page through [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.body) instead of jQuery("body"), and modify the HTML using [the `.innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) instead of [jQuery's `.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var replaced = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');
    document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
});
```

Comment: this is the nuclear option, it is going to remove any and all [] including valid ones, like the ones found in input names. See my answer for something that only hits the text nodes.

Comment: This yes it works. And i defentely will pick up this answer. But what if i want this to work only for a <td> with class="scanME"?

Comment: `var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td.scanME')` will look up those elements for you, but unlike jQuery the standard JavaScript DOM API won't let you modify all of those elements at once. You would need to write a `for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)` loop to modify each `cells[i]` in the same way as `document.body` was modified.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution, try `"Sometext [info]".replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');`

Comment: Well Sometext [info] is an example. Insted of it can be anything

Comment: I know, I just continued with your example :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what your doing is this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var replaced = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');
    document.body.innerHTML = replaced
});
```

That would be a silly idea though (speaking for myself)

Make your life easier & your site better by doing something like this

```
<p> Sometext <span class="tag-variable"> [info] </span> </p>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-variable');
    for( var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
      var current = tags[i]; // Work with tag here or something
      current.parentNode.removeChild( current );
    }
});
```