# jQuery replace all occurrences of a string in an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm working on a project where I need to replace all occurrences of a string with another string. However, I only want to replace the string if it is text. For example, I want to turn this...

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hi</h1>
  <h2 class="Hi">Test</h2>
  Hi
</div>
```

into...

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2 class="Hi">Test</h2>
  Hello
</div>
```

In that example all of the "Hi"s were turned into "Hello"s except for the "Hi" as the h2 class.
I have tried...

```
$("#container").html( $("#container").html().replace( /Hi/g, "Hello" ) )
```

... but that replaces all occurrences of "Hi" in the html as well

Comment: Try it! This question will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178174/find-all-text-nodes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This:

```
$("#container").contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/Hi/g, "Hello")
    if (this.nodeType === 1) $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Hi/g, "Hello") )
})
```

Produces this:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2 class="Hi">Test</h2>
    Hello
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j53xC/)**

Comment: This doesn't work if there are nested HTML tags, e.g. `<h2 class="Hi">Test <span class="Hi"></span></h2>`

Answer (score 9):

Nice results with:

```
function str_replace_all(string, str_find, str_replace){
try{
    return string.replace( new RegExp(str_find, "gi"), str_replace ) ;      
} catch(ex){return string;}}
```

and easier to remember...

Answer (score 8):

```
 replacedstr = str.replace(/needtoreplace/gi, 'replacewith');
```

needtoreplace should not rounded by  `'`

Answer (score 4):

```
//Get all text nodes in a given container
//Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4399718/560114
function getTextNodesIn(node, includeWhitespaceNodes) {
    var textNodes = [], nonWhitespaceMatcher = /\S/;

    function getTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (includeWhitespaceNodes || nonWhitespaceMatcher.test(node.nodeValue)) {
                textNodes.push(node);
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    getTextNodes(node);
    return textNodes;
}

var textNodes = getTextNodesIn( $("#container")[0], false );
var i = textNodes.length;
var node;
while (i--) {
    node = textNodes[i];
    node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/Hi/g, "Hello");
}
```

Note that this will also match words where "Hi" is only part of the word, e.g. "Hill". To match the whole word only, use `/\bHi\b/g`

Comment: This is by far one of the most under rated answers I have seen in a long time. It works extremely well even for running over the entire `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

here you go => http://jsfiddle.net/c3w6X/1/

```
var children='';

$('#container').children().each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Hi/g,"Hello")); //change the text of the children

    children=children+$(this)[0].outerHTML; //copy the changed child
});
var theText=$('#container').clone().children().remove().end().text(); //get the text outside of the child in the root of the element

$('#container').html(''); //empty the container

$('#container').append(children+theText.replace(/Hi/g,"Hello")); //add the changed text of the root and the changed children to the already emptied element
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are nested HTML tags, e.g. `<h2 class="Hi">Test <span class="Hi"></span></h2>`

Comment: In this particular example, but I think the OP was asking for a general solution. The example is probably a stripped-down version of his real HTML.

Comment: @MattBrowne you're right, j08691 's answer does it though

Comment: No it doesn't actually...I'll make the same comment there.