# JavaScript Replace function giving out errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this code to replace all ':)'s with my smiley emoji. Although when I run the code I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at ?v=0.02:10` any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>SVG Emoji</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html").innerHTML;
        html.replace(":)", "<img src='https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg'>");
        document.getElementsByTagName("html").innerHTML = html;
        </script>
        <h1>:) Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I have a much more refined answer if you are interested.

Comment: @EyuelDK Wow! Thanks works great going to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and the problem you are trying to solve are doing different things. This will give you the solution you are seeking, i.e. `replace all ':)'s with my smiley emoji`

```js
function replaceTextByImage(pattern, src) {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), 
    '<span style="background-size: 100% 100%; background-image: url(\'' + src + '\');">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span>'
  );
}

replaceTextByImage(':\\)', 'https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg');
replaceTextByImage(':P', 'https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpcom-smileys/twemoji/2/svg/1f61b.svg');
replaceTextByImage(':D', 'https://what.thedailywtf.com/plugins/nodebb-plugin-emoji-one/static/images/1f603.svg');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
    Hello World! How are you? :). Do you like this emoji :)
    </p>
    <div style="font-size:50px;">How about now :)</div>
    <div style="font-size:25px">You can also do this :P and this :D now!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PROS**

- Emoji will resize according to font used.
- Replaces all occurrences of a pattern

**CONS**

- If you have an inline script in the body of your html, it may be re-executed every time the function `replaceTextByImage` is called because it is setting the body's innerHTML.

Comment: How could I add a `:D` or `:P` to this?

Comment: I tried adding `:D`, `:P`, `:(` and `;)`. But it did not work.

Comment: simple error, fixed it. Note that it uses regular expression to match the symbols.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, but be ware of the deficiencies in such an approach. This is quick and dirty. I'll update my post to clarify the cons.

Comment: Is there a max of 3 emojis??

Comment: You can replace whatever you want, just call the function I've written with the pattern you want to replace along with the source image. You can replace all vowels if you want.

Comment: Oh I see I forgot the `\\\`` before the `)` and `(`'s thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html").innerHTML
```

with

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML
```

as `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.

Also, the [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method returns a new string without mutating / modifying the given one. You would need to re-assign the returned string to `html = html.replace(...)`.

Also, you need to move your `<script>` to the bottom. Otherwise it can't access DOM elements that appear beneath it in your HTML document, such as the `<h1>` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>SVG Emoji</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>:) Test</h1>
        <script>
        var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
        html = html.replace(":)", "<img src='https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg'>");
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = html;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

See also [How to get the <html> tag HTML with JavaScript / jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196971/how-to-get-the-html-tag-html-with-javascript-jquery)

For a more robust approach to replacing text within the DOM see [jQuery replace all occurrences of a string in an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109275/jquery-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-an-html-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I tried that just now, but it does not replace the `:)` with the image. The `:)` does not disappear and the image does not appear.

Comment: @csf30816 I think I fixed all of the errors by now :) - I really recommend the more robust approach I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem completely!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jquery then don't read this answer.
But for those who can allow their script not be jquery,
Here is your code.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].innerHTML = '<img src="https://csf30816.github.io/svg-emoji/emojis/smile.svg">';
```

```html
<h1>:) Test</h1>
```

What the problem is:
You are returning an array.
Use one element with [0]:
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = html;

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of "Use [0]:" I'd say "Access the first and only element by `array[0]`:" - PS: you can format a string as code by wrapping it in backticks: \`this is code\`.