# How to replace Text in html excluding tag properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add *TradeMark sign* **<sup>TM</sup>** next to the company name in the HTML.

Using below text:

```
<sup>TM</sup>
```

OR

```
&trade;
```

I have a rendered HTML, in which I have to add the trademark sign.

### HTML:

*Note: I have mentioned a small part of HTML body*

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="logo"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/logo.png" 
onClick="window.location='https://www.walmart.com'" 
alt="Walmart Inc"  title="This is Walmart Inc for your help" style="pointer-events:all" />
</div></div>

<div class="submenu">
    <a href="/blog" target="_blank">Walmart Inc Blog</a>
    <a href="/blog" target="_blank">New Walmart Inc Products</a>
</div>
<meta itemprop="brand" content=" Walmart Inc"><p>Welcome to Walmart Inc.</p>
```

### Tried below options:

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Walmart Inc/g, "Walmart Inc&trade;"));
});
```

above option replaces "HTML tag properties' values" i.e. **alt, title of img** as well, which I don't want.

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/Walmart Inc/g, "Walmart Inc&trade;"));
});
```

& this results in removing all the HTML tags from the body.

How to exclude text inside the properties of Tags while replacing?

### Desired Output:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="logo"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/logo.png" 
onClick="window.location='https://www.walmart.com'" 
alt="Walmart Inc"  title="This is Walmart Inc for your help" style="pointer-events:all" />
</div></div>

<div class="submenu">
    <a href="/blog" target="_blank">Walmart Inc™ Blog</a>
    <a href="/blog" target="_blank">New Walmart Inc™ Products</a>
</div>
<meta itemprop="brand" content=" Walmart Inc"><p>Welcome to Walmart Inc™.</p>
```

Comment: You can use a css solution for this. In the HTML code add a <span class='tradeMark'>Walmart Inc</span>. And in css do this : .tradeMark::after { content: '&trade'; }

Comment: As there are hundreds of pages, adding `<span class='tradeMark'>Walmart Inc</span>` everywhere cannot be done.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109275/jquery-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-an-html-page ???

Comment: On your second solution variation, you are setting each element's html using `$.html()`, but the value you set it too is being taken from `$.text()`. I believe `$.text()` is stripping tags and treating them as plain text.

Comment: @FreemanLambda, tried that also, It throws text, which eliminates HTML completely & gives text output only

Comment: Since this seems to be wordpress wouldn't it make more sense to do this in templates or database?

Comment: Apology if it looks like WordPress, but these are static pages in an html5 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach that only targets text nodes and replaces specific text node only with updated html. Will not affect attributes like `alt, title etc`

This will be superior to replacing larger blocks of html that may result in losing event listeners since you are only replacing text and no parent elements of that text

```js
var term = "Walmart Inc";

$('body *:contains("' + term + '")')
  .not(':has(:contains("' + term + '"))')
  .contents().each(function() {
    // nodeType for text nodes is 3
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.includes(term)) {
      var html = this.textContent.replace(term, term + '&trade;')
      // replace text node with html
      $(this).replaceWith(html)
    }

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="logo"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/logo.png" onClick="window.location='https://www.walmart.com'" alt="Walmart Inc" title="This is Walmart Inc for your help" style="pointer-events:all" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="submenu">
  <a href="/blog" target="_blank">Walmart Inc Blog</a>
  <a href="/blog" target="_blank">New Walmart Inc Products</a>
</div>
<meta itemprop="brand" content=" Walmart Inc">
<p>Welcome to Walmart Inc.</p>
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected. It excludes html tags.

Comment: Only place it might not work is a parent that has the standalone text that has a child with it also. Not sure if that will occur or not. Like `<div>Walmart <p>Walmart</p></div>`

Comment: Got it. For now, I don't have such case in my HTML, so overall it's working as expected

Comment: If it was me I would consider doing  a text replace in the files. Can use a regex to find instances that are only inside tags

Comment: That's the practice I also will prefer gladly. But I am not allowed to access the database.

Comment: And also, your solution works only for the first occurrence of text inside a tag

Comment: Ok.. can convert it to a regex within `replace()` and add `g` flag for multiples

Answer (score 1):

```
function insertTMAfter(name) {
    document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(item){
        if(item.children.length == 0)
            item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.replace(name, name + "&trade;");
    })
}

insertTMAfter("Stack Overflow");

// or in your case
insertTMAfter("Walmart Inc");
```

Comment: `&trade;` is an html entity and will not show as html if you use `innerText`.

Comment: Try it now! 
Thanks @Vikrant

Comment: updated code is working fine as expected & it's minimal code. But it doesn't replace the text in *Div's*