# Replace text with blank if value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a regular replace call, but I want it to also replace the whole part of the text with blank/empty space if nothing is entered in the input(data) area.
Here is the code and jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/6rhfdmfa/

Here is the div with input areas from which it gets the data:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="inputmeasurements">
        <p id="topmeasurement" align=left>
            <input type="text" class="topm" id="title" name="title" maxlength="80" placeholder="TITLE"><span id="counter"></span>

            <br>
            <input type="text" class="topm" id="specifics" name="specifics" placeholder="Specifics">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="topm" id="supplier" name="supplier" placeholder="Supplier">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="topm" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="topm" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="Weight">
            <br>
            <textarea class="topm" id="mercedes" placeholder="Enter Any Aditional Data Here"></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
        <p id="botmeasurement">
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="bust" name="bust">&nbsp;Bust
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="waist" name="waist">&nbsp;Waist
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="hips" name="hips">&nbsp;Hips
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="lng" name="lenght">&nbsp;Lenght
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="shl" name="shoulders">&nbsp;Shoulders
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="slv" name="sleeves">&nbsp;Sleeves
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="botm" id="ins" name="inseam">&nbsp;Inseam
            <br>
        </p>
        <div id="enter-meta-wrap">
            <p style="text-align: center;">Convert data to html ready metadata:</p>
            <button id="enter-meta" onclick="myFunction2();switchVisible();">Convert</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is where it will get entered:

```
<div id="finishedmeasurements" style="display:none;">
    <table id="grid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr onclick="clipboard(this);">
            <td>
                <p id="m1" align=center>TITLE&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>SPECIFICS&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>SUPPLIER | DATE | WT WEIGHT&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>MERC&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>
                    <br>B1 Bust inches flat&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>W1 Waist inches flat&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>H1 Hips inches flat&lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>L1 Length &lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>S1 Shoulders &lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>S2 Sleeves &lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>I1 Inseam &lt;/br&gt;
                    <br>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="new-meta-wrap">
        <p style="text-align: center;">Convert new data:</p>
        <button id="new-meta" onclick="myFunction3()">New</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current replace call:

```
//Convert input into formated metadata

function myFunction2() {
    var str = document.getElementById("m1").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/B1/g, document.getElementById("bust").value).replace(/W1/g, document.getElementById("waist").value).replace(/H1/g, document.getElementById("hips").value).replace(/L1/g,document.getElementById("lng").value)
    .replace(/S1/g, document.getElementById("shl").value).replace(/S2/g, document.getElementById("slv").value).replace(/I1/g, document.getElementById("ins").value)
    .replace("TITLE", document.getElementById("title").value).replace("SPECIFICS", document.getElementById("specifics").value).replace("MERC", document.getElementById("mercedes").value)
    .replace("SUPPLIER", document.getElementById("supplier").value).replace("DATE", document.getElementById("date").value).replace("WEIGHT", document.getElementById("weight").value);
    document.getElementById("m1").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of a few people, so I changed my old replace call in javascript with this:

```
function myFunction5() {
  var m1 = document.getElementById("m1")
  var str = m1.innerHTML
  var fields = [
    { regex: /B1/g, id:"bust"},
    { regex: /W1/g, id:"waist"},
    { regex: /H1/g, id:"hips"},
    { regex: /L1/g, id:"lng"},
    { regex: /S1/g, id:"shl"},
    { regex: /S2/g, id:"slv"},
    { regex: /I1/g, id:"ins"},
    { regex: /TITLE/g, id:"title"},
    { regex: /SPECIFICS/g, id:"specifics"},
    { regex: /MERC/g, id:"mercedes"},
    { regex: /SUPPLIER/g, id:"supplier"},
    { regex: /DATE/g, id:"date"},
    { regex: /WEIGHT/g, id:"weight"}]

  for (o of fields){
    var val = document.getElementById(o.id).value
    if (val != "")
      str = str.replace(o.regex, val)
    else // remove line
      str = str.replace(
        new RegExp("\\s+"+(typeof o.regex=='string'?o.regex:o.regex.source)+".*?\n")
        ,'')
  }
  m1.innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check for all html elements of type 'text' and then check their value if all empty then you can display as per your requirement.

Please refer [Find all text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178174/find-all-text-nodes)
for searching all text nodes in html using javascript

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not so savvy with javascript, so I am really stuck on how to make this work

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, in a way you've helped me get to my solution! :)

Comment: Glad to hear , You are encouraged to accept answer.